# File added programaticaly are not deleted when node is deleted

Tags: nodes, 8, files, media

I'm creating a node programmatically with one image field. Nodes are Created without any problem.

But if I delete the node the file is marked as "used in 0 place" but never deleted (I run the cron).

If I edit the node and delete the file of the image field, the file is still marked as "used in 1 place".

[image]

I want the file be deleted instantaneously like if I create the node using the node form.

```
/**
 * Create a new book from google data
 *
 * @param array $booksData
 * @return \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface\static
 * @throws Exception
 */
function book_market_create_book_node(Google_Service_Books_Volumes $booksData) {

  // Google_Service_Books_Volumes object automatically iterate, this will get data from the first book
  $bookData = $booksData[0];


  if (empty($bookData['modelData']['volumeInfo']['title'])) {
    throw new Exception('book data are incomplete');
  }

  $bookNode = Node::create([
    'type' => 'book',
    'moderation_state' => 'published',
    'title' => $bookData['modelData']['volumeInfo']['title'],
    'body' => $bookData['modelData']['volumeInfo']['description']
  ]);


  $imageLink = $bookData['modelData']['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'];

  if (isset($imageLink)) {
    $data = file_get_contents($imageLink);

    $transliterator = new Drupal\Core\Transliteration\PHPTransliteration(NULL, \Drupal::moduleHandler());
    $fileName = $bookData['modelData']['volumeInfo']['title'];
    $fileName = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName);
    $fileName = $transliterator->transliterate($fileName, 'fr', '_') . '.jpeg';

    $field_cover_settings = $bookNode->field_cover->getDataDefinition()
      ->getSettings();
    $destination = $field_cover_settings['uri_scheme'] . '://' . $field_cover_settings['file_directory'] . '/' . $fileName;
    $destination = \Drupal::token()->replace($destination);



    $file = file_save_data($data, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

    $bookNode->set('field_cover', [
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
    ]);
  }

  $bookNode->enforceIsNew();
  $bookNode->save();

  return $bookNode;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [known issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.2.6) of Drupal 8. There are several known problems with file usage and nodes. Depending on your situation they might contain useful information.

Comment: @Neograph734 thanks for the pointer. Perhaps also using file_save_data is creating the file entity independently of the node. But I don't know how to create the file entity "with" the node.

Comment: Files_save_data indeed does not register usage (if that is what you meant). That is what [file_usage_add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7.x) Is for.

Comment: @Neograph734 but because I set the node field field_cover with the file entity, drupal is smart enough to register usage, but not to delete the file. What I mean is perhaps I should create the file differently so Drupal understand this file is only used with this node and I don't need it when the node is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanent images are not deleted in Drupal 8, read this https://www.drupal.org/node/2891902

To remove the images, you can set `$config['file.settings']['make_unused_managed_files_temporary'] = TRUE;` in your settings.php. That should be it, it worked for me!

This will remove the permanent files when they are not in use anymore, depending on the time set in /admin/config/media/file-system

For example when you remove a node that contains an image, the image will not be removed at once. The image will be removed when cron executes and `make_unused_managed_files_temporary = TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that file will be delete when you run cron. File can't delete because temporary file have time life. You can see code in [file_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.module/function/file_cron/8.2.x).

```
function file_cron() {
  $age = \Drupal::config('system.file')->get('temporary_maximum_age');
  $file_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('file');

  // Only delete temporary files if older than $age. Note that automatic cleanup
  // is disabled if $age set to 0.
  if ($age) {
    $fids = Drupal::entityQuery('file')
      ->condition('status', FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT, '<>')
      ->condition('changed', REQUEST_TIME - $age, '<')
      ->range(0, 100)
      ->execute();
    $files = $file_storage->loadMultiple($fids);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $references = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
      if (empty($references)) {
        if (file_exists($file->getFileUri())) {
          $file->delete();
        }
        else {
          \Drupal::logger('file system')->error('Could not delete temporary file "%path" during garbage collection', array('%path' => $file->getFileUri()));
        }
      }
      else {
        \Drupal::logger('file system')->info('Did not delete temporary file "%path" during garbage collection because it is in use by the following modules: %modules.', array('%path' => $file->getFileUri(), '%modules' => implode(', ', array_keys($references))));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see line `if($age)` and line `->condition('changed', REQUEST_TIME - $age, '<')`. It's logic when run cron delete file.

And you can go **admin/config/media/file-system** to see time life of temporary file. Default are **6 hours**.

Comment: You right, majority of the file was deleted. Some still show usage but are "unlinked" from the original entity that was deleted. So their is two issue their.